# Lambda, Closures homework in python

Tags: python, function, lambda

I take a python class. I had many problems to resolve but this two gave me a headache. Any explanation please or some solutions ?

Write a script that retrieves a list of names. For each name:
   - if is longer that 5 chars, remove the consonants
   - if is shorter(or equal) then 5 chars, remove the vowels
   Order the resulting names alphabetically, and then print the concatenated string.
   Hint: Use functions for each action: removing the vowels/consonants(use lambda functions), string concatenation, ordering alphabetically.
         Use global constants.

Create a function that has as argument a number, named start_number.
   Using closures(defining a new function inside the first function), display the next 5 prime numbers, starting with start_number(argument from the enclosing scope).
   Example:
   start_number=11
   Results:  11, 13, 17, 19, 23

Answer (score 2):

```
def removeVowels(s):
    return s.translate(None,'aeiouAEIOU')
def removeConsonants(s):
    return s.translate(None,set(string.ascii_letters).difference('aeiouAEIOU'))
```

is one way of removing vowels and consonants